# Automator launching python script

Tags: macos, terminal, applescript, automator

So I'm trying to have a button in my Excel spreadsheet launch a Python script. Apparently this is only possible on Windows, so on the Mac version people have a workaround where they use Excel to launch an AppleScript which then launches a Python script.

In Automator I've tried selecting Application, and when that didn't work I selected Quick Action, and both times I inserted a 'Run Shell Script' module.

Within that I set the Shell to 'usr/bin/python' and Pass input as 'As Arguments'. Then in the text field I put

```
do shell script "/Users/user_name/Desktop/integrationtest.py"
```

and I tried

```
do shell script "python /Users/user_name/Desktop/integrationtest.py"
```

When I click Run in the top right of Automator it says

```
The action “Run Shell Script” encountered an error: “  File "<string>", line 1
    do shell script "/Users/user_name/Desktop/integrationtest.py"
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax”

  File "<string>", line 1
    do shell script "/Users/user_name/Desktop/integrationtest.py"
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Not too sure what I'm doing wrong - any ideas? Thanks for any help

Comment: I'll point out that Automator has a *Run Shell Script* action, which might give better results than trying to run your shell script from `do shell script` in AppleScript. I'm not really up on Excel buttons, though, so I'll have to look into that later.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing up AppleScript and Shell Script syntax.

- The **Run Shell Script** action syntax is

  ```
  python /Users/user_name/Desktop/integrationtest.py
  ```
- The **Run AppleScript** action syntax is

  ```
  on run {input, parameters}
      do shell script "python /Users/user_name/Desktop/integrationtest.py"
      return input
  end run
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to go step by step : first open Terminal application and test that your python script runs fine :

```
python /Users/user_name/Desktop/integrationtest.py
```

if OK, then open Applescript Editor and create a script with single line : (in Applescript, some environment settings may be different from usual bash Terminal)

```
do shell script "python /Users/user_name/Desktop/integrationtest.py"
```

If again this Applescript test works as expected, then call this Applescript from Excel. The method to call depends of your Excel version: With Excel 2011, use Macscript function, and with Excel 2016 use ApplescriptTask.